# css flex: фиксированная ширина блока в flex-контейнере с добавлением прокрутки

Tags: css, css3, flexbox, прокрутка, width

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при использовании flexbox ширина блоков не менялась (уменьшалась) в зависимости от кол-ва блоков `lane` в `board`, а вместо этого появлялась бы горизонтальная прокрутка (см. пример кода ниже)

```css
body {
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
    
    background: lightblue;
}

.board {
    display:                flex;
    align-items:            flex-start;
    flex-wrap:              nowrap;
        
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;
    
    background:             orange; 
}

.lane {
    display:                flex;
    flex-direction:         column;

    width:                  400px;

    margin:                 10px;
    padding:                0px;

    background:             white;
}

.task {
    display:                block;
    
    width:                  calc(100% - 2 * 5px);
    height:                 100px;
    
    margin:                 5px;
    
    background:             lightgreen;
}
```

```html
    <div class = 'board'>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: задайте min-width либо lane либо task.

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta, действительно помогло, спасибо, но возникла вторая проблема - родительский контейнер при этом не увеличился по ширине и элементы вышли за его пределы - как этого избежать можно? Т.е. чтобы родитель увеличился и вместил в себя все дочерние элементы

Comment: .board {width: min-content;} и 400px ширину уберите в .lane. У вас там видимо ширина все равно кальком задается.

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta, Ширину добавил чтобы гарантированно в примере за размер экрана вылезала

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
    background: lightblue;
}

.board {
    display: flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: min-content;  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;        
    background: orange; 
}

.lane {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: white;
}

.task {
    display: block;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: calc(100% - 2 * 5px);
    height: 100px;        
    margin: 5px;        
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
    <div class = 'board'>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
         <div class = 'lane'>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
            <div class = 'task'>TASK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```